# One class getting "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class..." But not the others

Tags: php, class, fatal-error

I am getting this error and not sure why.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DBC' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lpad.com/config/auth.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lpad.com/config/actions.php(3): Auth->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lpad.com/config/auth.php on line 8

All the other public functions that call this class, work perfectly fine.
DBC is my db connection class.
All the pages are require_once in the config.php file

auth.php

```
class Auth
{
    private $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new DBC;
    }

    // Login in Lead
    public function login($ld_id)
    {
        $this->db->query('SELECT ld_id FROM leads WHERE ld_id = :ld_id');
        $this->db->bind('ld_id', $ld_id, '');
        $result = $this->db->fetchSingle();
        return $result;
    }

    // Get Admin Sidebar Links
    public function getCats($ld_lp_access)
    {
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_access => :ld_lp_access');
        $this->db->bind('ld_lp_access', $ld_lp_access, 'int');
        $result = $this->db->fetchMultiple();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

action.php

```
require_once 'auth.php';
$auth = new Auth();

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'display_cats') {

    $output = '';

    $cats = $auth->getCats($ld_lp_access);

    if ($cats) {
        $output = '<ul>';
        foreach ($cats as $row) {
            $output .= '<li class="side-item"><a href="' . $row['cat_link'] . ' class="side_link"><i class="' . $row['cat_fa'] . ' fa-lg mr-1"></i>' . $row['cat_name'] . '</a></li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo 'No Categories Listed';
    }
```

ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  displayCats();

  function displayCats() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '../config/actions.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: 'display_cats'
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $("#showCats").html(response);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `auth.php` doesn't seem know about your DBC class - you need to require it as you have done with your Auth class in `actions.php`.

Comment: I have it require_once in the config.php file. And all the other functions are working fine in the Auth class. Also when I do require_once on the auth.php page, i get a slew of other errors.